correct tense: it hailed or it has hailed
I have made up the sentences below.
(1) Over the past three days, it hailed. However, it rained hard this morning. After the rain, it is now very windy.
(2) Over the past three days, it has hailed. However, it rained hard this morning. After the rain, it is now very windy.
Which tense of "hail" is correct? Thank you for your help.

The hailing is a past event, and hence we use the simple past, more so as it has already been
superceded by another past event, the morning rain.

ago would be better than over , because over implies a time frame that extends to the present.
